# Xamarin Image data is invalid on a stream copy

Tags: image, xamarin, stream

In the first case the code works fine.
In the second case I get:

> ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

So, case A (works fine):

```
Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker>().GetGalleryStreamAsync();
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Case B (error):

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker>().GetGalleryStreamAsync();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoryStream);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the last line

```
 Imgsrc= ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(memorystream));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from the line
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

The effect of this statement is to put the 'position' of the stream reader pointer at the end of the image stream.

If you follow this CopyTo statement with a 'stream.Position = 0;' then I believe all will be fine.